# XMLHttpRequest POST API Call

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Need help to find out why am I not getting any responseText back? I run this same API call on REST client with same parameters and I get response back fine but not through code. SignedToken is JWT token which should be sent in body.

```
            var xapicall = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xapicall.open("POST",'https://example.com/initauthn/do',true);
            xapicall.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            xapicall.onload = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    alert(this.responseText);
                }
            };
            xapicall.send(signedToken);
```

Comment: What browser are you using for the request? See https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_xmlhttprequesteventtarget_onload

Comment: Firefox 75 and Chrome 81, both supports as per the link you shared

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the dev tools console?

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry I didnt see it before. It says error in loading the JWT token.